# Python breaking out of tail -f process when remote process is done

Tags: python, buffer, paramiko, readline, tail

I have two processes running

1. `exeAPI` (running in the background with `nohup`)
2. `tail -f server.log` to output the remote server log

I am able to successfully see the output flush to my python client console like this:

```
@bp.route('/executeAPI', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def executeAPI():

    ...
    (ssh set up params)

    print('started...')
    data_buffer = ""
    stdin_run, stdout_run, stderr_run = client.exec_command('nohup echo source "exeAPI" | nc 127.0.0.1 40000 &')

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('tail -n 1 -f /home/server.log', get_pty=True)

    for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(1024), ""):
        data_buffer += line
        print(line, end="")
        if not data_buffer:          # never hits this if statement
            print('No more data')
            break

    print('finished.')
    client.close()

    return data_buffer
```

However, it never exits the `for loop` after the output is complete.

How can I break out of the `for loop` when there are no newlines?

Comment: Please strip / clean up your example code a bit. There is a return statement outside a function.

Comment: @code_onkel done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design `tail -f` doesn't exit when a process is done writing to the log file (it doesn't really know the difference between the log being done and the process just taking a really long time to write its next line).  What you probably want is `tail -f --pid=PID` if you can obtain the pid of your background process (for example by using `ps`).  According to the documentation this should terminate `tail` after the process with process ID PID dies.

Furthermore, the `if not data_buffer` check does not indicate `No more data`. The if condition will only be true, if `tail` returns without a single byte written to stdout, as `data_buffer` will be non-empty after the first non-empty line is read and appended. You could check `line` instead, but since you are using `iter()` with a sentinel value, this would be redundant.

Comment: Thanks, so I checked the `pid` and I do see the socket connection on pid 1422, however, there are also other sockets using that same `pid`, is there a way to `tail` that specific socket connection? I also tried using line but that didn't terminate the `tail` process.

Comment: Actually now that I look at what you're trying to do more, I'm not sure what you're going for.  I'm inferring that the `server.log` is the log file of the server at 127.0.0.1:40000.  Does it ever exit?  You're probably better off trying to put a semaphore in the log output that signals ending the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working using `re` and terminating the loop when I get a match of a unique string at the end.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!